# Obligatory transaction fee?

Tags: transaction-fees

I'm fairly new to bitcoin and today I sent 1 satoshi to my own adress using the standard wallet, and I was surprised that I couldn't do it without paying a 0.005 BTC (I think, can't remember the exact value) transaction fee.

As far as I knew transaction fee's were supposed to be voluntary, when did this get added? Is there no way to transfer bitcoins for free anymore?

Answer (score 1):

Transaction fees are voluntary but the client application is forcing the minimum transaction amount of .005.  It's been a long time since I've used the standard client.  .005 sounds correct.

Comment: Alright, is there any way to transfer coins between addresses without this fee?

Comment: I believe that there is an option in the settings to set the transaction fee.

Comment: @ColinDean, you know what, you might be right.  I think you can set something in a config file.  I think that still has a minimum value, though.

Comment: hustlerinc, I don't think so.  If you do your research, you could make RPC commands through bitcoind.  If you can build a raw transaction, you can build a transaction without any fees.